# Inputting a variable into a text file, using a batch file

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, text

So I'm trying to make it so that the user sets a password, and that password is loaded into a text file to be extracted for later use. The problem is, instead of typing the variable that the user inputs in the text file, it types 'ECHO is off' (or ECHO is on, if it's on).

Here is what I have written.

```
cls
set/p pass = Please enter your password:
> "p.txt" (@echo %pass%)
echo Password created!
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Thanks to MC ND, I have the solution! `set /p "pass= Please enter your password:"`

Comment: tip: highlight code and hit ctrl-K or click the `{}` button to turn it into a code block. manual workaround: indent each line with 4 spaces.

Comment: Marc B - Yeah, figured it out when I updated it. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to update your question with the answer, because the accepted answer is clearly visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces

```
set/p pass = Please enter your password:
          ^ This space is included in the name of the variable
```

So, your variable is named `%pass %`. Change to

```
set /p "pass= Please enter your password:"
```