# Dos Batch file user input showing blank

Tags: batch-file

I have spend lot of time but could not understand why entered value is showing blank in the echo command
Here is the execution:
Enter Name ssss
Entered name is ""

Thanks for your help

```
@echo off
:Input_cname
  echo .
  set c_name=
  set /p c_name  =  Enter Name 
  echo Entered name is "%c_name%"
  if not defined c_name goto Input_cname
  if /i "%c_name:"=%" == "end" GOTO End
:End
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
:Input_cname
  echo .
  set c_name=
  set /p c_name=  Enter Name 
  echo Entered name is "%c_name%"
  if not defined c_name goto Input_cname
  if /i "%c_name:"=%" == "end" GOTO End
:End
```

remove space before the equal sign because [it will became part of the variable name.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26023100/388389)